# Parametric integration of sigma times trigonometric

Tags: integration

How do I integrate $$
\int_{ -\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{- \frac{1}{2}x^2}}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}cos (ax) \space dx$$ where $a \in \mathbb{R}$?

I tried differentiating with repsect to $a$ but couldn't make much progress. Wolframalpha says the result is $e^{- \frac {a^2}{2}}$ but I can't see how it's derived. Can you help me?

Comment: This is easily done noting that 
$$e^{-x^2/2}\cos{(ax}) = Re\left\{e^{-x^2/2+iax} \right\}$$ where $Re$ means the real part of. You only have to integrate a shifted Gaussian. $$e^{-x^2/2+iax}=e^{-1/2(x+ia)^2-a^2/2}$$ 
Since the integral you proposed is normalised and $ia$ is a constant, $\textit{i.e.}$ it does not affect to the integral over $\mathbb{R}$, the final result is $$e^{-a^2/2}$$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral

Comment: Differentiate with respect to a and integrate by parts to find a differential equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**. A route within real-analysis. One may set
$$
f(a):=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-\frac12x^2}}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}\cos (ax) \space dx,\quad a \in \mathbb{R}.
$$ Then one is allowed to differentiate under the integral sign and one may perform an integration by parts, obtaining
$$
\begin{align}
f'(a)&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-\frac12x^2}}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}(-x \sin (ax)) \; dx
\\\\&=\left[ \frac{e^{-\frac12x^2}}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}\cdot \sin (ax)\right]_{-\infty}^{\infty}-a\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-\frac12x^2}}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}\cdot \cos(ax) \; dx
\\\\&=\color{red}{0}-af(a) \tag1
\end{align}
$$ The preceding ordinary differential equation can be solved,
$$
\frac{f'(a)}{f(a)}=-a,\qquad \log\left|\frac{f(a)}{C}\right|=-a^2/2, \qquad f(a)=C\cdot e^{-a^2/2},
$$ then using the gaussian result one finds that $C=1$ and we get

> $$
> \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-\frac12x^2}}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}\cos (ax) \; dx=e^{-a^2/2},\quad a \in \mathbb{R}.
> $$